# Locally dumping database data automatically when the project is executed

Tags: java, mysql, database, portability

I'm doing a programming coding challenge. It requires using databases. While I know how to create a database and insert all data in my computer, I have no idea how to make that the person, who will open my project from his computer, will have the data inserted into his local database. What should I do?

I'm using Java and MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I should use Docker for my case. Docker allows managing applications in Docker containers, without a need to install them on a host machine or a Virtual Machine.

https://hackernoon.com/local-database-with-docker-in-5-minutes-2c4862f17ae3

Answer (score 0):

You can take a dump of your mysql and programmatically run it to restore the sql.the below code will restore the dump into sql.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("mysql -p -h ServerName DbName < dump.sql");
```

to take the dump please follow the below link [dump](https://blog.winhost.com/using-mysqldump-to-backup-and-restore-your-mysql-databasetables/)

Comment: I don't know what server name should I type, since I don't know anything about the machine my code will be executed in. Besides, wouldn't person require to type his server password somewhere?

Comment: Yes in the server name the person who is going to run needs to give his server name

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to export your database:

```
mysqldump -u <yourusername> -p<yourpassword> <yourdb> > <yourfilepath>
```

And then on the other computer importing the database will be needed:

```
mysql -u <yourusername> -p<yourpassword> <yourdb> < <yourfilepath>
```